# Filtro avançado - Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, filter

Boa tarde,

estou a tentar efetuar um filtro avançado, com uma fórmula na célula.

Onde tem "Filtro individual atelier", em baixo "AT1" tem uma fórmula (célula X4):
*=SE(OU($T$3=1;$T$3=4);"x";" ")*

A minha dificuldade é, se eu tenho a fórmula (a avaliação da fórmula está correta, dá o valor que tem de dar), não funciona, se eu escrever diretamente a resposta, como por exemplo, "x", funciona.

Alguém sabe como resolver?
Obrigada.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Já está, obrigada.

Comment: Tem certeza de que não está funcionando? A fórmula que você colocou avaliaria para um espaço em branco, então, parece estar funcionando corretamente.

Comment: Sim.. se eu eliminar a fórmula, funicona, se deixar a fórmula avalia bem e está em branco, já não funciona..

Comment: Não consegui entender sua resposta ao meu comentário. Está funcionando ou não?

Comment: @CésarRodriguez, não está funcionando.

Comment: Entendi a resposta ao comentário, mas não consegui entender o problema. Você poderia explicar de outra forma?